# how to invoke the method of webservice with parameter?

Tags: java, jax-ws, soap-client, webservice-client, wsdl2java

I should invoke webservice to add a new user.
for this i used WSDL2JAVA to generate artifacts from WSDL

My Endpoint Interface has the different operation that i can invoke:

```
 @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "addUserReturn", targetNamespace = "url", partName = "addUserReturn")
    public User addUser(
        @WebParam(partName = "addUserRequest", name = "addUserRequest", targetNamespace = "url")
        UserRequest addUserRequest
    );
```

and my class USER have this:

```
  public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the firstName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setFirstName(String value) {
        this.firstName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the greeting property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }
```

this classes were generate automatically from WSDL 
and me i want implements this interface and invoke the method ADD bu i don't know how ? with request

FOR EXAMPLE: how invoke this method:

```
SoapService service = new SoapService();
SoapInterface inter = service.addUser(....); // here i don't know what i put 
// this parameter to refer  to : 
/*
 @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "addUserReturn", targetNamespace = "url", partName = "addUserReturn")
    public User addUser(
        @WebParam(partName = "addUserRequest", name = "addUserRequest", targetNamespace = "url")
        UserRequest addUserRequest
    ); */ 

Thanks ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pack the wsdl2java generated classes as a jar file and add it in class path and then intiate the `@WebMethod` class for calling the service.

Refer to the section "Coding the Client" in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnayl/index.html)

I assume you could do something like this.

```
        UserServiceImplService serviceImpl = new UserServiceImplService();

        UserService service = serviceImpl.getUserServiceImplPort();

        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
        userRequest.setFirstName("Tom");
        userRequest.setLastName("Jerry");

        User user = service.addUser(userRequest);
```

here is an example https://github.com/nkumarclm/jax-ws-example jaxws for your reference.

Also, another way is to use [jaxws-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) in your `pom.xml` which way you could keep the wsdl copy locally and generate all the required artifacts.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>web-services</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</wsdlDirectory> //location of your wsdl folder
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>user.wsdl</wsdlFile> //wsdl file name
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/generated/java</sourceDestDir>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

then you could simply autowire the `@WebMethod` class and invoke `addUser` method.

Comment: thanks, i did this but i want to invoke method with parameter to refer  ```

Comment: * <p>Java class for UserRequest complex type.
 * &lt;complexType name="UserRequest"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="" type="{http://...c}Options"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="user" type="{http://odum.service.odp.ondemand.ca.com}User"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;

Comment: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserRequest", propOrder = {
    "Options",
    "user"
}) ````  and the method invoked refer to      @WebMethod
    public com.ca.....User addUser(
        @WebParam(partName = "addUserRequest")
        com....service.UserRequest addUserRequest
    );

Comment: @Zenzouna  when you say "method with the parameter to refer" it is quite not clear to me. Could you please update the question with the details you provided in the above comments? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think it is provided in my answer. so you should initiate the class `UserRequest` which is present in the `java2wsdl` output and then populate the values and call the method `addUser` with the `userRequest` object as a parameter. 

        UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest();
        userRequest.setFirstName("Tom");
        userRequest.setLastName("Jerry");
        User user = service.addUser(userRequest);

Comment: like this :  user.setFirstName("test");
  option.setSendWelcomeEmail(false);
  UserRequest request = new UserRequest();
  request.setUser(user);
  user=port.addUser(request);
  System.out.println(user);

Comment: userRequest is just define the method setUser.  Class of User define SetFirstaname all object about user and ESI port call the method addUser, modify ....

Comment: if this the good way to call method request how to get the response and parse it to csv file or any type file ?

Comment: You are almost correct. UserRequest is your method parameter and you could do the same way as you commented above and it is the same in this answer and you get the object response as "User" that is the return object.  Parsing it to csv is not part of question still there are lot of plugins available to do that look at the supercsv plugin example here https://howtodoinjava.com/library/supercsv-parse-read-write-csv/